# ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded for a valid JSON file

Tags: python, json, parsing

I've a valid JSON file of size 109 Mgb with the following format representation.

```
[{"sensorType":"Radarcape","sensorLatitude":{"double":51.758894},"sensorLongitude":{"double":-1.256654},"sensorAltitude":{"double":200.0},"timeAtServer":1.429617600000027E9,"timeAtSensor":null,"timestamp":{"double":9.68628281E8},"rawMessage":"8d4008f999059a90c09719d7b430","sensorSerialNumber":13020235,"RSSIPacket":{"double":52.0},"RSSIPreamble":null,"SNR":null,"confidence":null}
,{"sensorType":"Radarcape","sensorLatitude":{"double":51.758894},"sensorLongitude":{"double":-1.256654},"sensorAltitude":{"double":200.0},"timeAtServer":1.429617600001544E9,"timeAtSensor":null,"timestamp":{"double":9.74843812E8},"rawMessage":"8f406a9a5913d2d51fbe8ab14fdf","sensorSerialNumber":13020235,"RSSIPacket":{"double":72.0},"RSSIPreamble":null,"SNR":null,"confidence":null}]
```

The simple code to read JSON file:

```
import json

with open ("jsonfile.txt",'r') as f:

        j=json.load(f)
```

I am trying to parse it to convert it to SQLite format. However, every time I get the following message error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/jsontosqlite/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    a=json.loads("newfile.json")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: `json.loads` should be passed a file object and not the filename. `with open('newfile.json') as f: 
     json.loads(f)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me if I put (exactly) the JSON data shown in your question into a `jsonfile.txt` file and run it:

```
import json

with open ("jsonfile.txt", 'r') as f:
    j = json.loads(f.read())

print(json.dumps(j, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "sensorType": "Radarcape",
        "sensorLatitude": {
            "double": 51.758894
        },
        "sensorLongitude": {
            "double": -1.256654
        },
        "sensorAltitude": {
            "double": 200.0
        },
        "timeAtServer": 1429617600.000027,
        "timeAtSensor": null,
        "timestamp": {
            "double": 968628281.0
        },
        "rawMessage": "8d4008f999059a90c09719d7b430",
        "sensorSerialNumber": 13020235,
        "RSSIPacket": {
            "double": 52.0
        },
        "RSSIPreamble": null,
        "SNR": null,
        "confidence": null
    },
    {
        "sensorType": "Radarcape",
        "sensorLatitude": {
            "double": 51.758894
        },
        "sensorLongitude": {
            "double": -1.256654
        },
        "sensorAltitude": {
            "double": 200.0
        },
        "timeAtServer": 1429617600.001544,
        "timeAtSensor": null,
        "timestamp": {
            "double": 974843812.0
        },
        "rawMessage": "8f406a9a5913d2d51fbe8ab14fdf",
        "sensorSerialNumber": 13020235,
        "RSSIPacket": {
            "double": 72.0
        },
        "RSSIPreamble": null,
        "SNR": null,
        "confidence": null
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. I wonder what was wrong with the way I wrote the the first code?!

Comment: @jelmoodjasser $10 says there's an unescaped quote or some other illegal character buried in that massive json file.

Comment: jelmood: Without having access to the actual file you're trying to load, it's impossible to say—although I don't agree with @Jared Smith.